# WebsitePanel can't find IIS_IUSRS Group

Tags: windows-server-2008, wmi, web-hosting, security

I've been trying to figure out why I can't add a website record to my domain on WebsitePanel.

The server is running `Win Server '08 R2 with IIS7.5

EDIT 1: Having tried going over this since before the OP date, I've downloaded the source for WebsitePanel and I've determined that the group that it can't find is in fact `IIS_IUSRS`.
**Anyone got any idea why a web application wouldn't be able to find this group?**

EDIT 2: After going through the code some more I've discovered that the web app (WebsitePanel) uses WMI to get a list of the user groups from the server. Thinking the issue could be caused by permission restrictions, I gave the web app full access to WMI which didn't improve anything.

This server is meant to host customer websites as well as my own (I deleted the website from IIS thinking there could've been a problem with the site already existing) so a speedy resolution to this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found...

In the WebsitePanels Web Server configuration, you can specify the group name that it'll use when creating websites.

Once I'd found this, I created the group that it was set to use and successfully added the website.